# R Convert number to month

Tags: r, date

I'm trying to build a time series. My data frame has each month listed as a number. When I use as.Date() I get NA. How do I convert a number to its respective month, as a date.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgSh5.png)

Comment: As your month does not contain a year, I wonder why simply *as.numeric* should not work?

Comment: Please read the posting instructions at the top of the [tag:r] tag page.  In particular show your data using `dput` as described there. Just posting images means that no one can use your data without retyping it.

Answer (score 1):

R Base has a built in month dataset. make sure your numbers are actually numeric by `as.numeric()` and then you can just use `month.name[1]` which outputs `January`

Answer (score 0):

Below we assume that the month numbers given are the number of months relative to a base of the first month so for example month 13 would represent 12 months after month 1.  Also we assume that the months re unique since that is the case in the question and since it is stated there that it represents a time series.

**1)** Let `base` be the year and month as a `yearmon` class object identifying the base year/month and assume `months` is vector of month numbers such that 1 is the base, 2 is one month later and so on. Since `yearmon` class represents a year and month as year + 0 for Jan, year + 1/12 for Feb, ..., year + 11/12 for Dec we have the code below to get a `Date` vector.  Alternately use `ym` instead since that models a year and month already.

```
library(zoo)
# inputs    
base <- as.yearmon("2020-01")
months <- 1:9

ym <- base + (months-1)/12
as.Date(ym)
## [1] "2020-01-01" "2020-02-01" "2020-03-01" "2020-04-01" "2020-05-01"
## [6] "2020-06-01" "2020-07-01" "2020-08-01" "2020-09-01"
```

For example, if we have this data.frame we can convert that to a zoo series or a ts series like this using `base` from above:

```
library(zoo)
DF <- data.frame(month = 1:9, value = 11:19) # input

z <- with(DF, zoo(value, base + (month-1)/12)) # zoo series
tt <- as.ts(z) # ts series
```

**2)** Alternately, if it were known that the series is consecutive months starting in January 2020 then we could ignore the `month` column and do this (where `DF` and `base` were shown above):

```
library(zoo)

zz <- zooreg(DF$value, base, freq = 12) # zooreg series
as.ts(zz) # ts series
```

**3)** This would also work to create a ts series if we can make the same assumptions as in (2).  This uses only base R.

```
ts(DF$value, start = 2020, freq = 12)
```